# loadPlayersForIdentifiers will not accept my array

Tags: ios, gamekit

i have this playersIDArray with playerID´s in Strings and give it the loadPlayersForIdentifiers classMethod. but i´ll get an error when i call this method. the string are not nil. i already checked this. in the documentation i read the method expects an Array with playerID-Strings. why is this not working?

```
NSArray * playersIDArray = @[ self.userIDString1, self.userIDString2, self.userIDString3, self.userIDString4 ];


    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:playersIDArray withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {

        if (players != nil) {

            GKPlayer *playerGlobal1 =   [players objectAtIndex:0];
            GKPlayer *playerGlobal2 =   [players objectAtIndex:1];
            GKPlayer *playerGlobal3 =   [players objectAtIndex:2];
            GKPlayer *playerGlobal4 =   [players objectAtIndex:3];

            self.globalPlayersArray = @[ playerGlobal1, playerGlobal2, playerGlobal3, playerGlobal4 ];
            NSLog(@"GKPLAYER ARRAY: %@",self.globalPlayersArray);

        }

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        }

    }];
```

Comment: Posting what the error you get is would be a really good place to start.

Comment: i deleted the project from my iphone and run it again and now it works.. i don´t know what that was but i didn´t change my code.. this is weird.. maybe i should reinstall xcode again.. since a few days i get more and more of this problems..

Comment: Don't reinstall Xcode, look up "clean" and "clean all".